# Is there any way to extract all the attribute names of an object in an Array in Java

Tags: java, csv

I'm going to accept a csv file which will have certain values. Those values will be validated againsts the attributes of an object

Example:

If there is a person class which has name,email,phonenumber etc.

```
public class Person{
private String name;
private String email;
private String status;

set();
get();
}
```

And the csv file has "name","email", I want to write a validation logic which will check the content of the csv against the object attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflexion, you can see which fields are in the class:

```
Field[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field curField:fields)
{
    System.out.println(curField.getName());
}
```

You can then take the field name form the csv and compare its value.

Comment: Please note that in the OP's example, the fields are `private`.

Comment: Right, I did not notice that, thanks for the comment. However, there is a way to enable them to be  available. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

Comment: @NPE, @J_D The OP needs only the field names and they should be visible with `getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: Than @J_D Also, if I have an object attribute in that Object like say private ContactInformation contact; and ContactINformation has String address, String phoneNumber etc. Is there a way to retrieve the attributes of the sub-object from the main Object using getDeclaredFields or something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with this solution. It's a predicate so it's reusable. Depends which predicate you use you can use it with guava or Apache Commons Collections.

```
public class BeanPropertyPredicate<T, V> implements Predicate<T> {

    // Logger
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanPropertyPredicate.class);

    public enum Comparison {EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL}
    private final String propertyName;
    private final Collection<V> values;
    private final Comparison comparison;

    public BeanPropertyPredicate(String propertyName, Collection<V> values, Comparison comparison) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.values = values;
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(@Nullable T input) {

        try {

            PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(input, propertyName);
            Object value = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(input);

            switch (comparison) {
                case EQUAL:
                    if(!values.contains(value))  {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case NOT_EQUAL:
                    if(values.contains(value))  {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to access property {}", propertyName, e);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```